# Javascript appending count to duplicates

Tags: javascript, duplicates, lodash

I am trying to use append the count to the duplicates using `lodash`.
For instance,

```
let arr = ["apple", "apple", "apple", "banana", "mango", "mango"];
```

Then I want my output to be

```
let modifiedArr = ["apple1", "apple2", "apple3", "banana", 
            "mango1", "mango2"];
```

Comment: `I am trying` - how? there is no code in your question

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Create a hashMap that will hold count of duplicate
- Push value to array as `value + count`

```js
let arr = ["apple", "apple", "apple", "banana", "mango", "mango"];
let hashMap = {};
const result = arr.reduce((p, c) => {
  hashMap[c] = (hashMap[c] || 0) + 1;
  p.push(`${c}${hashMap[c]}`);
  return p;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with an [ES6 Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const arr = ["apple", "apple", "apple", "banana", "mango", "mango"];

const result = arr.map(function(item) {
  const count = (this.get(item) || 0) + 1; // get the current count
  this.set(item, count); // update the map with the current count
  
  return item + count;
}, new Map()); // the map is the this of the callback

console.log(result);
```